# Classification with optional/catchall attributes

Tags: algorithms, classification, search-problem

### Context

Let $S$ be a set of objects, each object $S_k$ containing a set of attributes $A_k\subseteq A$, where $A$ is a global set of attributes. Suppose each attribute $a_k\in A$ can take on integer values $[1,m_k]$. Suppose also that the objects in $S$ are unique, i.e. no two objects contain the same attributes *and* the same values for those attributes.

Given a target object $X$ that contains values for all of $A$, I want to find the objects in $S$ that match $X$, matching constituting equality of values of all attributes between two objects. This sounds like a job for ID3, but here's the catch: *attributes an object in $S$ does not contain are catchalls: they match against any values of those attributes in $X$.*

I'm looking for something in the neighbourhood of $\mathcal{O}(|A|\lg(|S|))$ worst-case time and $\Theta(|S|)$ space, which if I understand correctly ID3 achieves. I haven't the faintest clue what kind of pre-processing tradeoffs exist, but it would be nice if construction were $\mathcal{O}(|S||A|)$ and insertion were $o(|S||A|)$ so that I didn't have to reconstruct the tree every time.

I'm leaning towards an ID3-like algorithm, but I don't know if its performance holds with the catchalls, since multiple branches can be valid on the same level.

Comment: You have a trivial $\Omega(|S|)$ lower bound; consider the case that *all* nodes match. Then assembling the output alone takes as much time.

Comment: @Raphael hmm... couldn't similar sets objects be clustered? I'd imagine that it might be possible for leaves to have multiple siblings, though I'll admit it sounds outlandish to have clusters linear or logarithmic in size to |S|...

Comment: Still, you'd want to copy them before returning, wouldn't you?

Comment: Are you looking for a practical solution (effective in practice)? or a theoretical solution (provable worst-case running time)?

Comment: @Raphael Haha, I suppose. Would it make any substantial difference if I returned $o(|S|)$ references to clusters? Eventually I'll have to perform an $\mathcal{O}(|S|)$ step when processing the results, sure. I'm just curious if I can avoid it with the searching alone, if it even makes that much of a difference.

Comment: @D.W. I wasn't sure there was much of a difference in this problem, but definitely a practical solution if there is.